# Which Qgis for OS X Yosemite?

Tags: qgis

Which Version of Qgis can I install on a Mac OS X Yosemite Version 10.10.2 ?

Comment: Have you looked at the download site for the package? "Lion or newer". http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis

Answer (score 1):

QGIS 2.8 is the latest version and is supported on OS X Lion or newer.